# Using Parse.com to retrieve a new array iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to use the parse.com data browser to inset a new string array into my code.

So if I've got a code with an array of @"blue", @"yellow", @"black", nil then how can I change it to @"white", @"gold", @"brown", nil ?

In the app, I have the user press a button and one of said string value appears at random. I would like to put a new array on a backend to have new values so that I don't have to update the app every time.

Is there an example of how to do this? I haven't been able to get the Data Browser to replace the array in my code with the array in the data browser.

I've got:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"colorArray"]; 
self.colors = [query findObjects];
```

But it crashes when I try to retrieve the values of the array when it gets to this part of the code in a later method -

```
NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.colors.count]; 
self.colorLabel.text = [self.colors objectAtIndex:index];
```

self.colors, by the way, is synthesized from the header file as an array. It looks like the code doesn't understand the "index" part of the equation when it tries to set the self.colorLabel.text using the obectAtIndex

The crash is  "-[PFObject length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb56740".

Am I doing this right?

Comment: What's the crash, what's the value of `self.colors`, and does that code actually compile? Or is that a typo?

Comment: The crash says -[PFObject length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb56740

Comment: self.colors is just the name of the NSArray, which I declare in the header and then synthesize in the implementation. The code does work in the simulator, but after I push the button to make a random string value appear (one of the color names) it crashes w/ the above crash.

Comment: Can you log the contents of the new array for us please?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `PFQuery`? `findObjects` returns an array of `PFObject` instances. You can't assign those to an `NSString` property. What property of the `PFObject` are you trying to access? EDIT: also, this looks like two questions in one, am I wrong? "How to replace a an array stored on parse", and "how to put the color name into a label".

Comment: In the NSLog it reads: "<colorArray:uowO3uDo86:(null)> {\n    colors =     (\n        Red,\n        Blue,\n        Black\n    );\n}"
)
That's when I put the NSLog in the viewDidLoad method. The name of my class on parse.com is colorArray

Comment: @CarlVeazey What I'm hoping to do is pretty much summed up in the first two sentences. I figure that once I can get a new array set up in the code, then putting them into the label won't be a problem. So really I'm just trying to find out how to use a back end to replace the values in the array I have established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.colors is an array of `PFObject`s - **not** `NSString`s

That is why this line fails:

```
self.colorLabel.text = [self.colors objectAtIndex:index];
```

What you need is something like:

```
NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.colors.count]; 
PFObject *colourPFObject = [self.colors objectAtIndex:index];
self.colorLabel.text = [colourPFObject objectForKey:@"columnNameForColour"];
```

Don't forget to change **columnNameForColour** to whatever name you call your colour column in your the Parse.com **colorArray** class

Comment: Thanks so much! Changing it up like this way exactly what it needed :)

Answer (score 0):

See the @Carl Veazey comment.

```
 {colors = (Red,Blue,Black);}
```

is from the description method of PFObject, you need to use the accessor methods of PFObject to get at the colors (or array of colors).